# angular js injector modulr error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to run this AngularJS example of a tutorial and the console says: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] when using restangular

Where is the problem?

```
<html >
<head>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/underscore/underscore.js" type="text/javascrixpt"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js" type="text/javascrixpt"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ang.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
var app=angular.module('angular',['ngRoute','restangular']);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check path to `restangular.js`. Also include `jquery.js` before `angular.js`.

Comment: also you have misspelling in type attribute of script 'text/javascrixpt'